# How to show all table names in luasql

Tags: sqlite, lua

guys. I want to display all table names in luasql sqlite3. I tried serveral ways but none of them succeeded. Can anyone help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table"`

Comment: is there a way to get name of the file(sqlite3 file)